# AJAX to get object and compare the json string data to the current value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, google-chrome-extension

my function will recieve a array object from a external api where i can convert that to JSON
lets say this is how my JSON objects look like

```
{
        "id": 99,
        "title": null,
        "author": "user",
        "content": "content",
        "url": "https://stackoverflow.comt"
    },

    {
        "id": 100,
        "title": null,
        "author": "user",
        "content": "content",
        "url": "https://www.google.com"
    }
```

after separating  particular key value pair from the above received data  this is how it looks

```
{"url":"https://www.google.com/"}
```

this process is async call as soon as i click on extension this gets triggered  and i can see that in console

now in my template 
popup.html

```
    <td>
                <input type="text" name="url" id="url">
                <input type="hidden" name="content" id="content" value="content" />
            </td>
```

popup.js

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true },
function callback(tabs) {
  var currentTab = tabs[0]; // there will be only one in this array
  $("#url").val(currentTab.url);
});
```

it grabs the current current url from the tab and sends to post.js where backend operations happen
now i want to check the url data and compare it to every url present in the JSON object

I'm new to Jquery/Javascript i tried comparing this value to each and every value to that json but its of no use

Answer (score 0):

When you have the json value of key value pair use the following code to get the url.

```
jsonKeyValuePair // assuming this variable has key value pair, having url.

var jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonKeyValuePair)
console.log(jsonData.url) // this should give you the url value 

// You can now compare

if(jsonData.url === currentTab.url) {
  // Do your calculation.
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and cleanest way you can compare is using Filter to match the urls in JSON object.

```
let currentTab = tabs[0]; // Url for comparing

//jsonObj contains all the json urls
let matchedUrl= jsonObj.filter(function(item) {
  return item.url === currentTab.url;
});

console.log(matchedUrl);
```

Comment: I wouldn't call it `Obj` as it's an array by the time it gets to `filter`

Comment: You can call it whatever you want as long as it gets the work done my friend.

Comment: It's true that the language environment will let you do that, but a good programmer also makes their code as clear to understand as possible. If you call variables whatever you want you're going to make things difficult for other developers (and 'other developers' includes you just a month or two down the line). It might get the immediate work done, but it's not going help getting the work done when you need to come back and fix bugs.